# First request from BizTalk WCF-Custom adapter not pre-authenticated

Tags: apache, wcf, apache-axis, biztalk

The first request (or batch of requests) I send from a WCF-Custom adapter using the wsHttpBinding (also tried basicHttp) does not include the Authorization Header.

**Request 1 Headers**

```
POST https://axis2service.com/HttpSoap12Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Host: axis2service.com
Content-Length: 556
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The service returns a 401 to which I respond with the below.

**Request 2 Headers**

```
POST https://axis2service.com/HttpSoap12Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Basic XXXXXX
Host: axis2service.com
Content-Length: 556
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

To which the axis2 on apache service responds with a 504 and **Connection: close**

This seems to be a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924638/en-us), how can I make request 1 include the *Authorization* header every time?

**Note:** The request 1 headers only get sent on the first request after a Host Instance restart. All subsequent requests from the adapter use the request 2 headers therefore bypassing the handshake stage.

Comment: The article references the HTTP Adapter but I do recall that adapter has slight behavioral differences with >1 message in the batch.  Anyway...try setting Ordered Delivery and see what happens.

Comment: @boatseller ordered delivery doesn't make a difference. I have a workaround: setting the retry interval to 0 still gives the 401 and 504 for the 1st message but it is retried straight after with the header. This is satisfactory but not ideal.